# How can I detect the iframe receive response when use hidden do ajax upload file

Tags: ajax, iframe, upload

I use hidden iframe do a ajax upload file job like this:

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/ajax-file-uploads-with-the-iframe-method/

```
<form target="upload-frame" method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
<iframe name="upload-frame" src=""></iframe>
```

the problem is, when upload success, and the iframe receive response and refreshed,

How can I know it refreshed? Is there any event to listen to the iframe content change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) One way to approach this would be to have the server send a response once the file is uploaded successfully like this (assuming PHP):

```
echo '<script>parent.document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "Success";</script>';
```

That will just inject the success message into the iFrame parent's #feedback container.

2) Another way would be to listen to the iFrame's load/onload event and attach an eventhandler to it which will read the body of the iFrame. Here's an example of that approach: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/

Hope that helps!